# Normalize a floating point

Tags: floating-point, normalization

I have a problem with a PLC (Programmable Logical Controller) which does not handle denormalized floating points.

Here's a few hex representations of the numbers (denormalized) I am receiving from the controller on the oposite side of my PLC:
0x00004180, 0x0000C180, 0x00006FA0

Would anybody be so kind to share a small code example (C++/C# or similar) on how to bitwise normalize a value similar to the above? I cannot use any float operations on the numbers since they are not recognized in the PLC, hence HEX/BIN operations only.

Precision is not a problem.

Comment: What format are these floats in?  IEEE 754 single-precision binary?

Comment: Denormalized floats are less than the lowest normalized float, "normalizing" them would either mean underflow to 0 or round up to FLOAT_MIN.

Comment: @Mark: IEEE 754, single precision

Comment: @hdl, OK so simply "rounding" to zero will be OK?

Comment: @kaare_t: Whether it's "OK" or not would depend on your application.  But it's not uncommon for embedded processors to flush denormals to zero.

Comment: @kaare_t Mark Dickinson said it all : depends on your application. If you only get denormals and their values are important, I'd say no of course. Then I'd advise you either to add an amplifier before your input so that you get less denormals or to use fixed-point arithmetic with the denormals you get if the first option cannot be used.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you I now understand what is happening. To explain a little for future reference: No, I only get denormals once in a while. Denormals in my application are, as you are saying, a nearly zero value and most often I get values around ~400.0 (this remote unit is a voltage monitor), but once in a while if the voltage drops to zero I get denormals. Hence I will simply check for all 0's in the exp, and then (if all 0's) simply force the value to zero since it has nothing to do with the actual measuring of the voltage. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a follow up to the question's comments, if you'd like to go for using fixed-point arithmetic:

Denormalized are less than **2^{-126}** and the fraction part has no implicit set leading bit, so basically a denormalized floating-point number is **0.mantissa * 2^{-126}**

You could fetch the mask in an int32_t and then have your floating-point value equal to **int_val * 2^{-126 - 23} = int_val * 2^{-149}**.
The number `23` is because binary32 format has 23 bits of mantissa. Of course you would store the integer value and the exponent value in different variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you have bitshifting with sign extension, a simple and branchless approach to flush denormals to zero is as follows (where `f` is the integer reinterpretation of the floating point number):

```
int32_t x = f & 0x7F800000; // mask out sign and mantissa
x += 0x7F700000; // overflows unless exponent is zero; MSB now indicates normalized
x >> 31; // sign-extend the MSB to all bits
f &= x; // flush denormals to zero
```